# How to calculate propensity score for temporal data

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, propensity-scores

I have temporal twitter data, and I want to calculate propensity score for the treatment and control group. The problem is, the treatment happened at different time for different user, and I want to compare aggregated values for covariates. For example, for user `a1`, treatment occurred after six months of account creation, for user `a2`, treatment occurred after eight months. I want to take the average number of tweets posted by those users before the treatment (for first six and eight months respectively), and find similar users in the control group who posted similar number of tweets for six and eight months. I have other covariates (e.g. average number of hashtags used). Is propensity score matching a suitable approach for this? If so how can I do that?

One approach came to my mind is to manually match one covariate at a time. This is similar to finding nearest neighbors, but for one dimension at a time. But not sure if this is a valid approach. If not what else I can do?

UPDATE: In our experiment, the treatment is the first tweet of an user that was retweeted more than a certain number of times. We want to compare for example, average number of tweets posted before and after the treatment by a user in treatment group with someone in the control group.

Comment: You need to shed more background on the problem. What is the "treatment" in this case? And in what sense does it causally depend on these other factors? The approach you describe doesn't seem to have anything to do with propensity scores.

Comment: @AdamO, thanks for you comment. Please see updated question.